# How can we fill the empty values in the column?

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have table A with 3 columns. The column (val) has some of the empty values. The question is: Is there any way to fill the empty values based on the previous value using python. For example, Alex and John take vale 20 and Sam takes value 100.

```
A = [ id name val
      1   jack 10
      2   mec  20
      3   alex  
      4   john
      5   sam  250
      6   tom  100
      7   sam
      8   hellen 300]
```

Comment: Need more specificity. What data type is your table? This would be easy in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to take in data as a pandas Dataframe and use the built in function fillna() to solve your problem. For an example,

```
df = # your data
df.fillna(method='pad')
```

Would return a dataframe like,

```
      id  name   val
0     1   jack   10
1     2   mec    20
2     3   alex   20 
3     4   john   20
4     5   sam    250
5     6   tom    100
6     7   sam    100
7     8   hellen 300
```

You can refer to this [page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) for more information.